# Rails: Error while uploading CSV file - "Validation failed: Email has already been taken"

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My rails app has CSV upload feature. It uploads CSV file of emails and saves it in customer database.

This is my view for uploading CSV:

```
           <%= form_tag import_customers_path, multipart: true do %>
                 <%= file_field_tag :file %>
                 <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
           <% end %>
```

This is customer model for uploading CSV:

```
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |customer|
                csv << customer.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
            end
        end
    end

    def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Customer.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
```

And my import action in controller is :

```
  def import
  current_user.customers.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to customers_path, notice: "Users imported."
  end
```

This is working great on localhost but on server i am getting error while uploading CSV:

```
   CustomersController# (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) "Validation failed: Email has already been taken"
```

It is working for one CSV file and not working for other.

**Edit:**

Just figured out that, my database has duplicate entries. And I have uniqueness validation on database. Actually users can upload CSV. So I want their records to be unique but some users might have common records.

So can somebody tell me how to generate unique records for users? Records in database can be redundant but every user will have unique records with no duplicate entries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems quite obvious (to me at least) that you're trying to create a customer for which there is already a `Customer` record which has that email address. I can't see your validations, so I'm going to assume there's both a `validates_presence_of` and `validates_uniqueness_of` in that `Customer` model.

Confirm that your CSV file does not contain customers with the same email address.

Comment: Hey, right i just figured out that my database had duplicate entries. I actually I was looking from user side. I need every user to have unique records who uploads their customer CSV file. But database can have duplicate records. Can you tell how to do that? Thanks. I updated my question too.

Comment: You probably want to validate it within the scope of something: `validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :user_id`